# Rails 4- How to create checkboxes in form where values come from a class variable thats an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, formbuilder, form-helpers

I have a model called task.rb as follows:

```
 # == Schema Information
 #
 # Table name: tasks
 #
 #  id            :integer          not null, primary key
 #  inputpath     :string(255)
 #  outputpath    :string(255)
 #  inputsize     :integer
 #  outputsize    :integer
 #  operator      :string(255)
 #  operationtype :string(255)
 #  created_at    :datetime
 #  updated_at    :datetime
 #

 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

 @@tasktypes = ["csv", "db"]

 def tasktypes
   @@tasktypes
 end


 end
```

What Im trying to do in the view rendered for the "new" action, I want to give the user an option as checkboxes to select one or many values from @@tasktypes that will be the value for attribute: "operationtype"

This is my form:

```
 <%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
   <% if @task.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

       <ul>
       <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
         <li><%= msg %></li>
       <% end %>
       </ul>
     </div>
   <% end %>

   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :inputpath %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :inputpath %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :outputpath %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :outputpath %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :inputsize %><br>
     <%= f.number_field :inputsize %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :outputsize %><br>
     <%= f.number_field :outputsize %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :operator %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :operator %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :operationtype , "What would you like to do with the file?"%><br>
     <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:operationtype,?? ,@@tasktypes, ?? %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

---

UPDATE:

I just made a slight change to the model attribute "operationtype" from string to text and also serialized it in the model see below:

```
 # == Schema Information
 #
 # Table name: tasks
 #
 #  id            :integer          not null, primary key
 #  inputpath     :string(255)
 #  outputpath    :string(255)
 #  inputsize     :integer
 #  outputsize    :integer
 #  operator      :string(255)
 #  operationtype :text
 #  created_at    :datetime
 #  updated_at    :datetime
 #

 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

serialize :operationtype, Array

@@tasktypes = ["csv", "db"]
#validates :inputpath, :outputpath, presence => {:message => "Must provide an inputpath and outputpath for file processing" }

 def self.tasktypes
@@tasktypes
 end



 end
```

As you can see above Im trying to figure out how to get the checkboxes to work. I would be grateful if someone can assist with this. Ive looked through the docs and there doesn't seem to be a way to make this work, but maybe there is a hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `check_box_tag` helper, kinda like that

```
<% tasktypes.each do |type| -%>
  <label><%= type %></label>
  <%= check_box_tag 'task[operationtype][]', type %>
<% end -%>
```

Although I'd have it as an array property on the model and then use the `select` helper with the `multiple` option switched on. Would be easier to track and handle the state of the picked values

Comment: I just changed the attribute for the operation type to array(test) please see the updated section above. Given this How to make this work using your suggestion of using select? Thx

Comment: It should look kind of like that `f.select :oprationtype, Task.tasktypes.map{|name| [name, name]}, multiple: true` see this link for more details http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select